# MySQL replication Slave_SQL_Running fails after inserting data

Tags: mysql, replication

For school I have to use master slave replication with MySQL on the same computer.

Since you can't run multiple instances of the same MySQL version on your computer, I'm using MySQL 5.6 for the master (port 3306) and MySQL 5.5 for the slave (port 3307).

After performing the following query:

```
stop slave;
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='localhost',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='MySQL_SLAVE',
MASTER_PASSWORD='mypasswordgoeshere',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000007',
MASTER_LOG_POS=1571;
start slave;
show slave status
```

I see both Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running is successful.

However, after inserting data in the master database, the Slave_SQL_Running value switches from 'Yes' to 'No'.

The Last_Error column gives this:

1594 - Relay log read failure: Could not parse relay log event entry. **The possible reasons are: the master's binary log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the binary log), the slave's relay log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the relay log), a network problem, or a bug in the master's or slave's MySQL code.** If you want to check the master's binary log or slave's relay log, you will be able to know their names by issuing 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' on this slave.

Using the mysqlbinlog command on the binary logs of my master and slave I see no errors.
Since I run these two instances on one computer I'm pretty sure my problem isn't caused by a network problem. Since I just imported the master's data to the slave's data, I'm pretty sure this also isn't caused by the MySQL code.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing binlog_format from 'ROW' to 'MIXED' on the master.

Comment: @ChamindaBandara https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html

`SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';`

Comment: I will try, Thank you